Decomposition of Differential Forms
Bott-Tu's Differential forms in algebraic topology says every differential form over $\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R=\{(x,t)\}$ uniquely decomposed into two types of forms, one type with $d t$ and one type without $dt$, and they use this kind of decomposition in the book several times to define homotopy operator and pushforward. The idea is simple, if we call the fiber term $dt^J$, then the process is to decompose a form into type II which has enough ''$dt$" so that $|J|=\text{dim} F$, and type I which doesn't so $|J|<\text{dim} F$.
However, they didn't say why this process is well-defined in section 4, although they did leave an excercise in section 6 which shows that this process doesn't depend on the trivilization, so we can construct the pushforward from local to global case. But I want to do this globally, so we must show this decomposition is unique for a general product bundle $\pi:M\times F\to M$. Let $\rho:M\times F\to F$. My questions:
(1) Is there a unique decomposition $\omega\in\Omega^n(M\times F)$ into forms: $\sum_k\omega_k$, where each $\omega_k=f_k\pi^*(\phi_k)\rho^*(\tau_k)$ for some $f_k\in \Omega^0(M\times F),\phi_k\in\Omega^k(M),\tau_k\in\Omega^{n-k}(F)$.
(2) What about a nontrivial orientable bundle $\pi:E\to M$?(Here we don't have a global projection $\rho$, but I think orientability must imply there is a global form $e$ that plays the role of $dt^J$)
(3) Will things be different in the case of compact supported case or compact vertical support case?
Remark: We are not looking for a Kunneth Formula on cochain level which is not true, but looking for something like $$\Omega^n(M\times F)=\bigoplus_k\Omega^0(M\times F)\wedge \text{Im}(\psi_k)$$ where $\psi_k:\Omega^k(M)\times\Omega^{n-k}(F)\to\Omega^n(M\times F)$ is the wedge product of pullback.

What does $\rho$ mean here?

The projection $\rho:M\times F\to F$.

There is no such projection except in the case of a trivial bundle.

Yes, I first consider the trivial bundle $M\times F$. I think there is some anologue as $\rho^*(\tau)$ or $dt$ in case of $\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R$ if the bundle is orientable

You might want to read the various posts discussing integration over the fiber.
